# I have deleted a table from models but django still looking for it

Tags: python-3.x, django

[image]I have deleted a model name controlapproval from my database by commenting the model and
Running **python manage.py makemigrations**
but when i try to migrate by using **python manage.py migrate**
It throws an error as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 19, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 261, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.delete_model(model)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 308, in delete_model
    super().delete_model(model)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 326, in delete_model
    "table": self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\FBR\FBRENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: assessment_controlapproval
```

Any help or guidance will be a great help

Comment: Did you by any chance _manually_ delete the table yourself from the database?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your `migrations` folder from your project root.
2. Create a new `migrations` folder.
3. Add a `__init__.py` empty file in that folder.
4. Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

This will just create a fresh migrations for your project.

Comment: the project is a live application so I cant delete the migrations fully

Comment: It will only delete migrations. Your database's data won't be affected.

Comment: i know that but when im going to upload it to server they will have to delete there migrations as well which will affect the work off other team members working on the same project

Comment: @HussainPettiwala is there a reason this answer is almost verbatim of your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68071797/issue-creating-django-models/68073004#68073004) one? Please refrain from such actions, if you feel that it answers this question too then _flag the question as a  duplicate_ instead of reposting it.

Comment: The question is totally different but the solution is the same.